# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create the build file with the below command.

```
cordova build android
```

Here's the issue I am getting

> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':zipalignDebug'.
>   File '/home/user/applications/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.1.0/zipalign' specified for property 'zipAlignExe' does not exist.

From one of the answers I found and downloaded the `zipalign` file and put that into my file structure of sdk under tools directory.

But even then I got the same error.

What's wrong.

Comment: maybe you should update your Android sdk. I have the version 23.0.2 installed and it works fine. Are you able to call zipalign from command prompt? If not you shoud index the path of your build-tools in system variable.

Comment: I just updated to 22

Comment: Maybe after updateing you have to remove and add the platform anroid in your project.